# How to parse objdump output data?

Tags: disassembly, objdump

I'm somehow newbe in reverse engineering and currently I'm reading [RE4B](https://github.com/ckonstantinou/re4b/blob/master/RE4B-EN.pdf) book.

[image]

In the image above:

1. I can't figure out the role of `s` in the functions `f1` and `f2`. As far as I know, based on the last line in the image (i.e. `s     db 'world', 0xa, 0`), the variable `s` is a pointer to the beginning of *world* string. So, why this value is over-writed with *-1C* in the functions? (`s = dword ptr -1Ch`)
2. As you know, we can use stack to pass function arguments. The question is why the compiler used `mov [esp+1Ch+s], offset s ; "world\n"` instead of `mov [esp], offset s ; "world\n"`?